# Will advertising for a special event increase my chances of getting mystery parts?

Tags: pocket-planes

By special event, I mean the top-level, global events that last for days and have the flight crews and prizes. The current one has prizes that are parts for the starcraft, so I'd like to increase my chances of getting the extra parts via the mystery parts.

Answer (score 2):

Special parts in the game are gained 
at random times usually in class 3 
Airports. Advertising increases flights 
Demand to that airport for normal cargo
 or people.